# return value (Python best practices)

Tags: python-3.x

I have one function (F1) returning the values of (a, b, c)
and other function (F2) using those values. I need to check on F2 if "a is None".

This is the first function (F1)

```
def get_info():
   msg = get_msg()
   number = get_number()
   if msg is not None:
      return msg, number
   return False, False
```

Secound function (F2)

```
def save_log():
   msg, number = get_info()
   if msg:
      do_more_stuff
```

If I don't do `return False, False` in the first function I get `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable` in the second function.
Do I have a better way of returning those values other than `return False, False`.

What is the pythonic best practice in this situation?
Thanks

Comment: It's impossible to say without knowing what the caller code is supposed to be doing with the return values.  As a general rule: `return False, False` from a function called `get_info` is a code smell - use exceptions instead.

Comment: Have you considered raising an error in `get_msg` instead of returning `None`?

Comment: The function name in the example is fake sorry for that lol. I always try to give a meaningful name to functions and variables. So I use exceptions all over the place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what a solution using errors/exceptions would look like.  `get_msg` (and maybe `get_number` if applicable) would raise an exception when they fail to return a value, instead of returning a value that indicates failure.

```
class MessageRetrievalError(Exception):
    pass

def get_msg():
    message = message_code()
    if message is None:
        raise MessageRetrievalError
    return message

def get_info():
    return get_msg(), get_number()

def save_log():
    try:
        msg, number = get_info()
        do_more_stuff
    except MessageRetrievalError:
        do_other_stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback.